# Handle react event and legacy library event together

Tags: reactjs

For example, when i wrote a dropdown class, my thought is like this

```
EVENT.listener(document, 'click', function(e) {
     // hide all active dropdowns
});

var DropDown = React.createClass({
    onClick: function(e) {
        // toggle self
        e.stopProbagation();
    }
});
```

However, the event in react and outside are different; so, the above code won't work. So, how to handle this? or is there another pattern to write the dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

[`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) is the best place to integrate other frameworks or native calls since React guarantees a component's real DOM node exists when `componentDidMount` is called.

To get similar functionality to your example, you could implement the function in your root React component and listen to the native DOM event there. When the click occurs, call into any components using their `ref` attributes that need to react to the click:

```
var RootComponent = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.hideOverlays, false);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.hideOverlays, false);
  },

  hideOverlays: function() {
    this.refs.dropdown.hide();
  },

  render: function() {
    return DropDown({ref: "dropdown"});
  }
});

var DropDown = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      isVisible: false
    };
  },

  hide: function() {
    this.setState({isVisible: false});
  }

  render: function() {
    var style;
    if (!this.state.isVisible) style = {display: "none"};

    return React.DOM.div({style: style});
  };
});
```